# Xamarin.Forms UnhandledException when doing a request

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to use the HttpClient PCL from Microsoft in an Android project but whne I attempt to make a request, after a little while I get a "System.Diagnostics.Mono_UnhandledException" and no extra info.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_apiUrl);
var resourceUrl = "setistas?login=" + login + "&senha=" + senha;
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, resourceUrl);
var response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
```

I am not sure why this happens, I am using the latest version of Xamarin studio, and the latest version of the libraries.

Can anyone help me?

By the way don't mind fact that I am passing secure information on the url, this is just a test. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not awaiting your request and trying to read result of unfinished task.
Last line should be

```
var result = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

Comment: he's calling it in-line with the `.Result`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on how I referenced the libraries.
When you add the nugget package for HTTPClient to the DLL project, you have to add a reference in the Android project to System.Net.Http, once you do that, it starts working.